# Linked Server Configuration using remote user logins

Tags: security, linked-server, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to configure a Linked Server using remote logins reducing who has access to the linked server by taking advantage of the not be made option. For test purposes alone, I have used SA, obviously I won't be using that going forwards however I just wanted to make sure the procedure worked and SA having all privileges would cater for this.

Again for troubleshooting purposes, I initially tried SA using the 'be made using this security context' option which worked well but obviously is not secure as I want to reduce who has access to the linked server.

When I tried the 'not be made' option with a local and remote login I receive an error suggesting that no login mapping exists although the login worked when I used the 'be made using this security context' option. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084453/sql-linked-server-yields-error-no-login-mapping-exists-if-non-admin-account-is

Comment: Hi @SqlWorldWide, yes I have and a sa login does exist on the remote server

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the `Impersonate` option or not use `sa` for testing—use another SQL Login instead for testing this functionality. I'm not 100% certain it's required but you may also need to consider ensuring the remote logins have a matching `sid` on both SQL Server instances as I wrote about in the [User mapping to a standby database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173642/user-mapping-to-a-standby-database/173768#173768) post if you do not use impersonation so something easy enough to test using `sp_helplogins` and `CREATE Login` if needed.

### Why

I don't recall where I heard or read about it, or if it's even applicable in this case, but I thought the `impersonate` rights were inherited implicitly for logins with `sysadmin` and local `db_owner` rights.

> **Impersonate**
>
> Pass the username and password from the local login to the linked
>   server. For SQL Server Authentication, a login with the exact same
>   name and password must exist on the remote server. For Windows logins,
>   the login must be a valid login on the linked server.
>
> To use impersonation, the configuration must meet the requirement for
>   delegation.
>
> ---
>
> **Not be made**
>
> Specify that a connection will not be made for logins not defined in
>   the list.
>
> [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

### Impersonation

If you go with using impersonation, below are a couple syntax examples to use for domain user account logins and local SQL logins which connected to the `master` DB.

```
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::[domain\username1_to_be_impersonated] TO [domain\username2]
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::[user1_to_be_impersonated] TO [user2]
```